# Debugging with Gdb in RISCV (spike: unrecognized option --gdb-port)

Tags: gdb, riscv

After building the RISCV tools and GCC (cloned [from lowrisc](https://github.com/lowRISC/riscv-tools), [isa-sim](https://github.com/lowRISC/riscv-isa-sim) and [not riscv-tools](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools)), i'm stuck in the debugging with Gdb phase [here](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim#debugging-with-gdb).

In the second terminal target remote in `gdb` times out.

In the first terminal when i run `spike --gdb-port 9824 pk tests/debug` or `spike --gdb-port 9824 pk hello.c` it yields:

```
spike: unrecognized option --gdb-port
usage: spike [host options] <target program> [target options]
Host Options:
  -p <n>             Simulate <n> processors
  -m <n>             Provide <n> MB of target memory
  -d                 Interactive debug mode
  -g                 Track histogram of PCs
  -h                 Print this help message
  --ic=<S>:<W>:<B>   Instantiate a cache model with S sets,
  --dc=<S>:<W>:<B>     W ways, and B-byte blocks (with S and
  --l2=<S>:<W>:<B>     B both powers of 2).
  --extension=<name> Specify RoCC Extension
  --extlib=<name>    Shared library to load
```

I don't know if it has to do with configuring `gdb` on its own ? Or is it built and configured when i ran `./build.sh` for the riscv tools.

If not, could you please correct the `--gdb-port` command (I'm new to linux) I've tried `--gdb-port=9824` or `--gdb-port:9824` and it's the same.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Message `spike: unrecognized option --gdb-port` says that `spike`, not `gdb` can't recognize option. Spike is from riscv-isa-sim, not from riscv-tools. And LowRisc variant of Spike - https://github.com/lowRISC/riscv-isa-sim is many commits behind master:

> This branch is 3 commits ahead, 172 commits behind riscv:master.
>   Latest commit e220bc4  on May 19, 2016 @wsong83 wsong83 Merge commit '0d084d5' into update

One of not ported commit added gdb support to spike from https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim (and documented it in https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim#debugging-with-gdb), but it is not pulled to https://github.com/lowRISC/riscv-isa-sim (and not documented at https://github.com/lowRISC/riscv-isa-sim). gdb-related commits were from Oct 2016, Jun 2016, May 2016, and the --gdb-port was added in  d1d8863086c57f04236418f21ef8a7fbfc184b0b (Mar 19, 2016) https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim/commit/d1d8863086c57f04236418f21ef8a7fbfc184b0b

```
+  fprintf(stderr, "  --gdb-port=<port>  Listen on <port> for gdb to connect\n");
+  parser.option(0, "gdb-port", 1, [&](const char* s){gdb_port = atoi(s);});
```

You can [try merging changes](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim/compare/master...lowRISC:master) between isa sims or ask lowRisc authors to merge or **just** try to **use spike from [riscv](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim)**...

Comment: Hello, I tried removing the riscv-isa-sim directory and replacing it with the current one and rebuilt everything but it still didn't work.

Comment: @ninode, current one from where? Use https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim spike.

Comment: Yes. I did use that one.
Stupid question: Should I really configure all directories separately ? Or just running ./build in riscv-tools does it ?

Comment: @ninode, don't know about ./build. Do you have exact same error message with riscv/riscv-isa-sim's spike, or error is different?